# ERROR TypeError: ctor is not a constructor

Tags: angular, angular-cli, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

```
ERROR TypeError: ctor is not a constructor
at createClass (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:138903:24)
at createDirectiveInstance (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:138780:24)
at createViewNodes (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:147112:40)
at Object.createEmbeddedView (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:147020:9)
at TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:138495:42)
at ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:138361:39)
at NgIf._updateView (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:323486:49)
at NgIf.set [as ngIf] (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:323448:22)
at updateProp (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:139056:41)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (/opt/lampp/htdocs/2.3.0/gwp-web/dist/server.js:138807:23)
```

I installed @ng-toolkit/universal then

> npm run build:prod

build success.
But when

> npm run server

I have a problem like the one above.
Can someone tell me what should I do?
I use Angular 8.

Comment: Try to find out which class is causing the issue by modifying server.js to add logs laybe